# Site connecting very slowly in Chrome - DNS Issue

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-elb

I have a site which is hosted in AWS EC2 instance with a ELB URL. The DNS mapping is done.
When I try to open the site in Chrome it takes about 1.3 mins to open whereas in Safari it takes about 3 secs. On investigating further I found out that the initial connection is taking 1.3 secs and subsequently it takes 3-4 secs to load the website. Is this a DNS issue?
Need help to solve this issue as I am not a network expert.
Thanks for your help.

Sukrity

Comment: What makes you think it is a DNS issue? Does it take 1.3 seconds if you ping it? What does it do if you immediately reload it? and then again after a flushing DNS? You would probably need to investigate a little more to understand what is going on but it seems unlikely to be a DNS issue (IMHO)

Comment: Hi Michael - It might not be a DNS issue. I don't have much knowledge about DNS settings hence I was thinking it was a DNS issue since the site loads very fast in safari but takes a long time to connect in Chrome. To answer your question in the same Chrome session if I reload it immediately comes up. Can you please suggest what other possible investigations can be done.

Comment: For me I was only using 1 availability zone (only 1 EC2 instance) so I had to remove the unused (and unhealthy) one from the Load balancer). Posted this as answer to another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55777470/908677