# AWS ELB is extremely slow and patchy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, elastic-load-balancer

I have setup internet-facing ELB to access webserver of Apache airflow, which runs in 8080 of the instance.

Configuration

1. Single-AZ ELB
2. Autoscaling group with single m4.large instance

Below is the terraform resource for the ELB

```
resource "aws_elb" "airflow_elb" {
  name = "${var.domain_name}-elb"
  subnets = [
    "${aws_subnet.private.id}"]

  security_groups = [
    "${aws_security_group.public.id}"]

  "listener" {
    instance_port = 8080
    instance_protocol = "http"
    lb_port = 80
    lb_protocol = "http"
  }

  health_check {
    healthy_threshold = "${var.elb_healthy_threshold}"
    interval = "${var.elb_interval}"
    target = "HTTP:8080/admin/"
    timeout = "${var.elb_timeout}"
    unhealthy_threshold = "${var.elb_unhealthy_threshold}"
  }

  access_logs {
    bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.bucket}"
    bucket_prefix = "elb-logs"
    interval = 60
  }

  cross_zone_load_balancing = false
  idle_timeout = 400
  connection_draining = true
  connection_draining_timeout = 400



  tags {
    Name = "airflow-elb"
  }

}
```

I can ssh tunnel to the private-ip instance via bastion host and the portal works without any issue. But when I access via the DNS name of the ELB it is either extremely slow, in which case I can see the request is reponded almost instantaneously from the webserver, but takes forever to load or ELB throws HTTP 503

Please help!!

EDIT1: Backend processing time is very high, but I can see that happens only when accessed from ELB, when done from tunneled connection it behaves normally.

Comment: Have you tried bypassing the ELB and hitting your instance directly, like http://{your_instance_ip}:8080 ?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned above, it works well if done that way

Comment: `"${aws_subnet.private.id}"`  An Internet-facing ELB should not be in a private subnet.  But also, if this is indeed a private subnet, the ELB should not be working at all.  ELBs should *not* usually be in the same subnets as the instances they are balancing, but many people seem to assume the opposite.

Comment: @sqlbot thanks will try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually with using sync worker with python 3 and how ELB reuses http connection. The issue disappeared after changing from sync worker to gevent. However gevent is not supported as of yet by python 3, so we r stuck with python 2.7 for now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Classic ELB According to [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ts-elb-error-message.html#ts-elb-errorcodes-http503)

Three Reasons Stated there are :

**Cause 1:** Insufficient capacity in the load balancer to handle the request.

**Cause 2:** No registered instances.

**Cause 3:** No healthy instances.

Login to Console and see if instances are registered under ELB and if they are, are they in healthy state ?

Also I am curious why have you used only one AZ ?

Comment: Everything checks, instance is registered and healthy

Comment: are ports mapped working properly also can you share logs from s3 as I can see you have enabled logging

Comment: As I said, the portal works and the connection is not down, but patchy, works at time and doesn't work at time, and when it works it is very very slow

Answer (score 0):

A few helpful resources when diagnosing ELB issues:

- ELB [latency troubleshooting](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-latency-troubleshooting/)
- ELB [logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/access-log-collection.html)
- ELB [metrics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/elb-metricscollected.html#loadbalancing-metrics-clb)

Comment: The problem is backend seems fine, I was able to tunnel port 8080 and it portal works really well from my machine's browser, and elb access logs has very low backend latency as well, ELB is breaking things and have no clue why

Answer (score 0):

You can try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42300647/2727462

> Solution If you're DNS is configured to hit directly on the ELB -> you
>   should reduce the TTL of the association (IP,DNS). The IP can change
>   at any time with the ELB so you can have serious damage on your
>   traffic.
>
> The client keep Some IP from the ELB in cache so you can have those
>   can of trouble.
>
> Scaling Elastic Load Balancers Once you create an elastic load
>   balancer, you must configure it to accept incoming traffic and route
>   requests to your EC2 instances. These configuration parameters are
>   stored by the controller, and the controller ensures that all of the
>   load balancers are operating with the correct configuration. The
>   controller will also monitor the load balancers and manage the
>   capacity that is used to handle the client requests. It increases
>   capacity by utilizing either larger resources (resources with higher
>   performance characteristics) or more individual resources. The Elastic
>   Load Balancing service will update the Domain Name System (DNS) record
>   of the load balancer when it scales so that the new resources have
>   their respective IP addresses registered in DNS. The DNS record that
>   is created includes a Time-to-Live (TTL) setting of 60 seconds, with
>   the expectation that clients will re-lookup the DNS at least every 60
>   seconds. By default, Elastic Load Balancing will return multiple IP
>   addresses when clients perform a DNS resolution, with the records
>   being randomly ordered on each DNS resolution request. As the traffic
>   profile changes, the controller service will scale the load balancers
>   to handle more requests, scaling equally in all Availability Zones.

In my case the problem was in TTL. Issue can be tracked by a command like `wget https://your-url`. The comand output will show you the IP address to which it tries to connect. And when connection hangs you can figure out a wrong outdated IP address. If it happen - check your DNS settings and update TTL.